# How to make FASTAPI pickup changes in an API routing file automatically while running inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I am running FastApi via docker by creating a sevice called ingestion-data in docker-compose. My Dockerfile :

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

# Environment variable for directory containing our app
ENV APP /var/www/app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Define working directory
RUN mkdir  -p $APP
WORKDIR $APP
COPY . $APP

# Install missing dependencies
RUN pip  install -r requirements.txt
```

AND my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    ingestion-service:
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        restart: always
```

I am not sure why this is not picking up any change automatically when I make any change in any endpoint of my application. I have to rebuild my images and container every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer: Yes :)

In the Dockerfile, you copying your app into /var/www/app.
The instructions form the Dockerfile are executed when you build your image (`docker build -t <imgName>:<tag>`)
If you change the code later on, how could the image be aware of that?

However, you can mount a volume(a directory) from your host machine, into the container when you execute the `docker run` / `docker-compose up` command, right under /var/www/app. You'll then be able to change the code in your local directory and the changes will automatically be seen in the container as well.

Perhaps you want to mount the current working directory(the one containing your app) at /var/www/app?

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/app
```