# FastAPI in docker container: how to get automatic detection of changes in python file?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I was looking to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038345/how-to-make-fastapi-pickup-changes-in-an-api-routing-file-automatically-while-ru) but for some reason it does not work for me.

I have the following folder structure:

```
api.service
- app
-- main.py
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
docker-compose.yml
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, HTTPException, Request, Body

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World!!!"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: str = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  api-service:
    build: ./api.service
    ports:
      - "8180:80"
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - ./api.service/app:/app/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.11

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt
```

I tried to play with volumes in docker-compose as well as with Dockerfile but no luck so far.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? if you want to change the file of some python executable it will not work until you reload the application. Similarly, when you run a Python application in the IDE, if you change the text of the file, it will not immediately apply the changes until you reload the script

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#development-live-reload ? If you want to have live reloading, you have to invoke `uvicorn` with a flag - which the default script doesn't do.